# python add to a list only if there is no match

Tags: python

I have a list of rhel packages that starts with "redhat-release"

I want to filter out packages that has notes in them like:

redhat-release-notes-5Server-5.x86_64

I am looping over the list of packages

```
CV_PKG_RHEL_LST = []
for pkg_name in cv_packages_dic['results']:
    h_rl_server = pkg_name['nvrea']
    if re.match("redhat-release-notes", rh_rl_server) is  None:
        CV_PKG_RHEL_LST.append(rh_rl_server)
```

and trying to add only those packages that doesn't contains the string starting

with: redhat-release-notes

but its not working for me its including packages that contains
"redhat-release-notes"

How do I filter out of the list the packages that contains:
"redhat-release-notes" ?

Comment: You meant to use `re.search` not `re.match` which is automatically anchored to the beginning of the string. But really, you should just use `in`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a substring you can use `in` with the instruction `not` before it:

```
CV_PKG_RHEL_LST = []
for pkg_name in cv_packages_dic['results']:
    h_rl_server = pkg_name['nvrea']
    if "redhat-release-notes" not in rh_rl_server:
        CV_PKG_RHEL_LST.append(rh_rl_server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular expressions: re.match() checks for a **match only at the beginning** of the string, while re.search() checks for a **match anywhere** in the string (this is what Perl does by default). [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

With `re.match()`, you need pattern add `.*` (python add `^` @ the beginning of the pattern) :

```
CV_PKG_RHEL_LST = []
for pkg_name in cv_packages_dic['results']:
    h_rl_server = pkg_name['nvrea']
    if re.match(".*redhat-release-notes", rh_rl_server) is  None:
        CV_PKG_RHEL_LST.append(rh_rl_server)
```

or better using `re.search()` :

```
CV_PKG_RHEL_LST = []
for pkg_name in cv_packages_dic['results']:
    h_rl_server = pkg_name['nvrea']
    if re.search("redhat-release-notes", rh_rl_server) is  None:
        CV_PKG_RHEL_LST.append(rh_rl_server)
```

Answer (score 0):

the pythonic way to do this is to use list comprehension like the following:

```
 CV_PKG_RHEL_LST = [ pkg_name['nvrea'] for pkg_name in cv_packages_dic['results'] if "redhat-release-notes" not in pkg_name ]
```

Comment: list comprehension is almost always faster than an explicit for loop.